# Is there a difference between pointer in main / function

Tags: c, function, pointers

I've been experimenting with pointers: 
I wanted to output an array using double pointers. It worked, but when I tried the same with a function it did not work anymore. Somehow the pointers don't seem to be connected.
Does anyone have an idea what the error could be.

```
#include <stdio.h> 



void out2pointer(char *ptr, char **ptrptr);

int main(){
    char out[3][3] = {{'a','b','c' },
                         {'d','e','f' },
                         {'g','h','i' }};



    char *ptr = &out[0][0]; //pointer
    char **ptrptr=&ptr;     //pointerpointer

    out2pointer(ptr,ptrptr);

    ptr = &out[0][0];
    ptrptr=&ptr;

    printf("\nOutput in main:\n");

    for(int i=0;i!=3;i++){
        for(int k=0;k!=3;k++){
            printf("%c",*ptr);          //output in main
            *ptrptr=*ptrptr+1;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void out2pointer(char *ptr, char **ptrptr){
    printf("\nOutput in Function:\n");
    for(int i=0;i!=3;i++){
        for(int k=0;k!=3;k++){
            printf("%c",*ptr);          //output in Funktion
            *ptrptr=*ptrptr+1;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Please include your text output as text in the question. No need to include a picture of text.

Comment: Traversing a two-dimensional array as if it were an one-dimensional array, sometimes called flattening the multidimensional array, invokes undefined behaviour according to the Standard, but _mostly_ works in practice. I wouldn't recommend using that technique in real programs.

Comment: There are some good answers here, but it might help to learn that c passes everything by value (aka copies). When you pass `ptr` to the function, `out2pointer()` receives a **copy** of the address that `ptr` points to. This article explains more: https://denniskubes.com/2012/08/20/is-c-pass-by-value-or-reference/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have 2 different variables `ptr` in `main` and `out2pointer`.

If you do this in `main`

```
    ptrptr=&ptr;  // ptr from main

    for(int i=0;i!=3;i++){
        for(int k=0;k!=3;k++){
            printf("%c",*ptr);          // ptr from main
            *ptrptr=*ptrptr+1;          // Modifies ptr from main.
        }
    }
```

then `*ptrptr = *ptrptr+1` actually modifies `ptr`, i.e. the `ptr`variable visible in `main`.

When you pass those pointers to `out2pointer` then you introduce another variable `ptr` that is only visible in the function and that is not related to the variable with same name from `main`.

Then in your function you always print `*ptr` which is not changed during your nested loops. Instead `*ptrptr=*ptrptr+1;` still modifies the `ptr` variable from `main` but does not affect local variable.

```
void out2pointer(char *ptr, char **ptrptr){
    for(int i=0;i!=3;i++){
        for(int k=0;k!=3;k++){
            printf("%c",*ptr);          // This is the ptr from the function.
            *ptrptr=*ptrptr+1;          // *ptrptr points to ptr from main!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In `main` function `*ptrptr` aliases the `ptr` - they designate the same object and therefore by changing `*ptrptr` you also change `ptr`.

Within the other function, `*ptrptr` designates the `ptr` variable of **`main`**, but the `ptr` within the function is *a different variable* whose value was initially set to the same value. Therefore changing `*ptrptr` will change value of  `ptr` in `main` but will have no effect on the distinct parameter by the same name in the function.

Finally, according to the C standard, incrementing the `int *` past the end of the inner array, or deferencing such a pointer, has undefined behaviour. That would happen when printing the letter `d` of the array or when incrementing the pointer so that it points to the `e`.

Answer (score 1):

In function `out2pointer` `printf("%c", *ptr);` isn't correct, you need `printf("%c", **ptrptr);`.

And the function doesn't need `ptr` argument at all. That `ptr` is a copy of the `ptr` you pass into `out2pointer`, and this is why it is not affected by `*ptrptr=*ptrptr+1;`

Comment: You should describe *why* OP's code is incorrect and how this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have to send the address of `ptr` to the out2pointer(**char, **char). And yes, the out2pointer function declaration has to be changed.

The reason is you have to pass `ptr` by **reference** and not by **value**.

Because `ptrptr` is pointing to a whole new pointer variable `ptr` in `out2pointer(char*, char**)`(*hence, we need to change the declaration as shown below*) function.

Hence, when you increment `ptrptr`, it doesn't affect the `ptr` variable in `out2pointer(char*, char**)`.Because `ptrptr` in `out2pointer(char*, char**)` is pointing to `ptr` of `main` function, and not the `ptr` in `out2pointer(char*, char**)`.

let's understand why this happens,

```
In main,
assume &out[0][0] = 0x1111.*(assuming its a 16-bit machine)*
assume &ptr = 0x2222.
Hence, it can be inferred from your code that,
ptr = &out[0][0] = 0x1111.
*ptr = out[0][0] = 'a'.
ptrptr = &ptr = 0x2222.
*ptrptr = ptr = 0x1111.
**ptrptr = out[0][0] = 'a'.
After, *ptrptr = *ptrptr + 1 (in main), we have
**ptrptr = 'b', and *ptr = 'b'
```

And, after function call to `out2pointer(char*, char**)` in `main`,

```
In out2pointer(char*, char**),
assume &ptr = 0x3333.*(because its a new local variable)*
Hence, it can be inferred from your code that,
ptr = &out[0][0] = 0x1111.
*ptr = out[0][0] = 'a'.
ptrptr = 0x2222.(still pointing to 0x2222 and not 0x3333)
*ptrptr = ptr = 0x1111.
**ptrptr = out[0][0] = 'a'.
After *ptrptr = *ptrptr + 1 (in out2pointer(char*, char**)), we have,
**ptrptr = 'b' and *ptr = 'a'.(because, pointer at memory location 0x2222 was incremented, whereas pointer at 0x3333 remains unchanged, and you are printing the variable at 0x3333 in out2pointer(char*, char**)).
```

Everytime when you increment `ptrptr` in `out2pointer(char*, char**)`, you are incrementing variable at memory location `0x1111`, but the variable `ptr` of `out2pointer(char*, char**)` is in memory location `0x3333`, which is not incremented. Hence `ptr` points to `'a'` in every loop iteration.

***METHOD 1:***

modify `out2pointer` function declaration:
`void out2pointer(char** ptr, char** ptrptr); // yes, we need **ptr`

modify `outpointer2` function call in main():
`out2pointer(&ptr, prtptr); // pass the address of ptr and and the value`

And finally in function definition of `out2pointer(char**, char**)`, modify `printf` like this:
`printf("%c",**ptr)`

***METHOD 2:***

Another method would be to reassign the `ptrptr` in `out2pointer(char*, char**)` to &`ptr`.

By, doing this `ptrptr` will point to the local variable `ptr`(local to `out2pointer(char*, char**)`), and not the `ptr` in `main` function.

**And yes, this method needs less changes compared to the previous one.**

***Thank You for the question***